# Tourism on Business Visa in Japan

Tags: visas, tourist-visas, japanese-visitors

I have a "multiple entry Business Visa" expiring in 2021. I wish to visit Japan for the purpose of tourism (or maybe to watch the Olympics in 2020).

I have absolutely nothing to do with the business now. Do I need to apply and get a tourist visa now?

PS: I don't see any term "business" on my visa. The category of visa mentioned is "(V) AS TEMPORARY VISITOR"

Answer (score 1):

There is no real distinction any more between a Japan "business" or "visitor" visa. You can use either for business and tourism.

See the [Application Procedures for Multiple Visa for Nationals of India](https://www.mofa.go.jp/files/000121950.pdf), effective from January 2019, where it is explained:

> The visa is for the purpose of tourism, business affairs,  and  visits  to  relatives/acquaintances,  so  it  is  not  permitted  to  perform  activities  to  undertake  revenue generating business operations or activities to receive remuneration.

Even if your visa was originally a "Multiple Visa for Nationals of India for business purpose, and cultural or intellectual figures" you can use it again for tourism after the first visit.

> The  visa  is  for  the  purpose  of  business  affairs  for  the  first  visit,  but  from  the  second  visit  it  is possible to use as tourist or visiting to relatives/ acquaintances as well. But it is not permitted to perform activities to undertake revenue generating business operations or activities to receive remuneration.